# Find all repeating strings between a start and a stop and with a separator

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, delimiter, multiple-matches

I'm trying to get one or more substring from a string like this :

> "theSTART:param1:param2:paramN:theEND"

or

> "theSTART:param1:theEND"

or any number of parameter saparated by ":" and delimited by "theSTART:" and ":theEND".
I'm using Python3 regex but I can't find the right pattern to match a variable number of items:

```
r"theSTART:((?:\w*)+):((?:[^:])*):((?:\w)+):theEND"
```

works only for 3 items.
And if I try :

```
r"theSTART:((?:\w*)+):(((?:[^:])*):)+((?:\w)+):theEND"
```

doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

re.findall might be a solution if you want to use regular expressions instead of splitting. findall returns a list of all occurrences of a pattern.

```
re.findall(r":(?:(\w+)(?=:))", r"theSTART:param1:param2:paramN:theEND")
```

returns the list `['param1', 'param2', 'paramN']`.

You probably won't (or can't) find a pattern to match any number of parameters. According to the Python [re module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.group) is only the last match accessible, if a group matches multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

Well, if your data always starts with 'theStart', ends with 'theEnd' and all fields are ':' delimited then why even fool with regex for the problem? Why not just:

```
def delimited_items(the_string):
  items = the_string.split(':')
  return items[1:-1]
```

Comment: I'm trying to solve this with regex to better understand how to form patterns and get more familiar with python regex. Anyway your solution is useful to.

Answer (score 0):

Capturing everything using '.' then splitting on the delimiter should simplify things a bit.

```
params = re.match(r'theSTART:(.+):theEND', a).group(1).split(':')
```

Answer (score 0):

#### You can use `re.findall` with a `positive lookahead`:

**See a demo on [`regex101`](https://regex101.com/r/YeqjEy/2)**

The link above will explain very well what each part of the `regex` below does in detail, but if you are still not sure, try reading the [`documentation`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) as it is very useful.

```
s = "theSTART:param1:param2:paramN:theEND"
re.findall(":(.+?)(?=:)", s)
```

which gives a `list` of the `parameters`:

```
['param1', 'param2', 'paramN']
```

*N.B. there are two different smiley faces `:)` in this which is pretty cool*